# php header information warning error

Tags: php

i know this a duplicate question but i try all the answers in the same questions but i still cant fix it. The error shows that header cannot be modified and when i click the login button the user is logged in but it not go to the index.php page. When i try to put the "if(isset($_POST['login']))..." codes in the top its working but the javascripts are not working. please help guys..

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Sign In</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="index.php"><img src="img\home.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:3px; width:16px; height:16px;">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="speaker.php"><img src="img\speakers.png" style="margin-bottom:-1px; margin-right:4px; width:15px; height:13px;">Speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php"><img src="img\about.png" style="margin-bottom:-1px; margin-right:3px; width:13px; height:12px;">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php"><img src="img\contact.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:6px; width:13px; height:14px;">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="reservation.php"><img src="img\reservation.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:5px; width:14px; height:13px;">Reservation</a></li>
            <li><a href="signOut.php" id="signOut"><img src="img\signOut.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:6px; width:14px; height:14px;">Sign Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="myAccount.php" id="user" style="text-transform:capitalize;"><img src="img\user.png" style="margin-bottom:-1px; margin-right:6px; width:13px; height:12px;"><?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="signUp.php" id="signUp"><img src="img\signUp.png" style="margin-bottom:-1px; margin-right:6px; width:13px; height:11px;">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="signIn.php" id="signIn"><img src="img\signIn.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:6px; width:14px; height:13px;">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="adminControl.php" id="adminControl"><img src="img\admin.png" style="margin-bottom:-3px; margin-right:6px; width:15px; height:16px;">Admin control</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="pull">Speaker Reservation</a>
</nav>

<div id="register-wrapper">

    <div id="register-container">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <p>Please provide the information below.</p>
    <hr>
    <div id="alert"> 
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
    Wrong Username or Password
    </div>
    <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST">
    <input name="email" class="inputbox" type="email" autofocus required="required" maxlength="30" placeholder="Email Address">
    <div class="popup">
    <img  class="formIcons" src="img\questionMarkIcon.png" onclick="helpMessageEmail()">
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">The email address you used to create your account</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input name="password" class="inputbox" type="password" autofocus required="required" maxlength="30" placeholder="Password">
    <img class="formIcons" src="img\questionMarkIcon.png">
    <br>
    <input name="login"  id="buttonsubmit" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
<div id="footer">Copyright 2017</div>

<script>
$(function() 
    {
        var pull = $('#pull');
        menu = $('nav ul');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();
        $(pull).on('click', function(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function()
        {
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) 
            {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
function helpMessageEmail() 
{
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");

}
</script>

<script>
function alert() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifAdmin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("signIn").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signUp").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifNotAdmin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("signIn").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signUp").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifNotLogin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("user").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['signedIn']) && $_SESSION['signedIn'] == true) 
        //if login
        {
            if($_SESSION['type'] == 1)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifAdmin();</script>";  
            }
            elseif($_SESSION['type'] == 0)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifNotAdmin();</script>";
            }
        }
        //if not login
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifNotLogin();</script>";   
        }
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "srdatabase";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, password, emailaddress, contactnumber, type, status FROM accounts WHERE emailaddress = '$email'";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($query)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $id = $row[0];
        $dbFirstName= $row[1];
        $dbLastName= $row[2];
        $dbPassword = $row[3];
        $dbEmail = $row[4];
        $dbContactNumber = $row[5];
        $dbType = $row[6];
        $dbstatus = $row[7];

    }

    if($email == $dbEmail && $password == $dbPassword)
    {
        if($dbType == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $dbFirstName;
            $_SESSION['lastname'] = $dbLastName;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $dbEmail;
            $_SESSION['contactnumber'] = $dbContactNumber;
            $_SESSION['signedIn'] = true;
            $_SESSION['type'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['status'] = $dbstatus;        
            header("location:index.php");
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $dbFirstName;
            $_SESSION['lastname'] = $dbLastName;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $dbEmail;
            $_SESSION['contactnumber'] = $dbContactNumber;
            $_SESSION['signedIn'] = true;
            $_SESSION['type'] = 0;
            $_SESSION['status'] = $dbstatus;    
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert();</script>";    
    }
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

this is the image of warning 
[image]

Comment: This is so basic I don't know how "the answers in the other questions" didn't show you what is wrong. You can't have *any* output before you call header(),*period*.

Comment: and what is that output may you explain further

Comment: everything outside of `<?php ?>` is output. and everything an echo, a print, a print_r, ... does.

Comment: simple 
FIRST : 

<?php
    session_start();
?>

Then : 
<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: sorry but putting IDOCTYPE below is not working but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You can't have **anything** at all before it. No spaces, no HTML, no text, just PHP code that doesn't print anything.